# Not able to export data to an excel sheet

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel

I am using to_xls and spreadsheet gem to export data to excel sheet in rails4

However, I am not able to export the data to excel sheet even if the excel sheet fires open.

I am following this tutorial

http://code.dblock.org/2011/09/01/exporting-data-to-excel-in-ruby-on-rails-w-spreadsheet-and-toxls.html

orders_controller.rb

```
def index
  @orders = Order.all.includes(:status,:document,:platform, payment: 
            [:status]).where(status_id: Orders::Status.where(name: 
            ['INPROGRESS', 'COMPLETED']).pluck(:id)).paginate(:page => 
            params[:page], :per_page => 30).order('id Desc')

  @order_statuses = Orders::Status.all

  @delivery_statuses = Orders::DeliveryStatus.all 
                       respond_to do |format|  
                       format.html
                       format.xls do
                       send_data( 
                                  Order.where(status_id:         
                                  Orders::Status.where(name: 
                                  ['COMPLETED',
                                 'INPROGRESS' ]).pluck(:id))
                                 .includes(:status, :platform,
                                          :payment).map{
                                          |order|
                                          {  
                                   id: order.id, txnid: order.txnid,
                                   created_at: order.created_at,
                                   product: order.product,
                                   payment:                    
                                          order.payment.status.name, 
                                  status: order.status.name,   
                                  total_amount: order.total_amount,     
                                  discount: order.discount, 
                                  platform: order.platform.name 
                                  }}.to_xls,
                       content_type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                       filename: 'orders.xls' )
                    end
                  end
                end
```

orders/index.html.erb

```
<table id='myOrdersTable'class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Trans ID</th>
  <th>Date(dd/mm/yy)</th>
  <th>Product</th>
  <th>Payment</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <th>Total amount</th>
  <th>Discount</th>
  <th>Platform</th>
  <th>Draft</th> 
  <th>Edit Draft</th>
  <th>Upload Soft Copy</th>
  <th colspan="3"></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= order.txnid %></td>
    <td><%= order.created_at.strftime('%d-%b-%Y') %></td>
    <td><%= order.product %></td>
    <td><%= order.payment.status.name if order.payment %></td>
    <td><%= order.status.name %></td>
    <td><%= order.total_amount %></td>
    <td><%= order.discount %></td>
    <td><%= order.platform.name %></td>
    <td
        :
        :
        :

  <% end %>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <%= will_paginate @orders %>
        :
        :
 <%#= link_to 'New Order', new_order_path %>
 <%= link_to 'Exporting', "/admin/orders.xls", :class =>'btn btn-primary' 
  %>
```

Here in the link if call

```
 <%= link_to 'Exporting', orders_path(request.parameters.merge({:format
  => :xls})), :class =>'btn btn-primary' %>
```

it gives a template missing error(Dont know why) .Hence I am not using the above link in the code to get the export button.
This helps me generate an excel sheet, but not able to export all the columns from the index.html.erb page and their values into the sheet. Just gives a blank spreadsheet. How can I export all these data in to sheet? Please help !I am a beginner so kindly elaborate and let me know if more data is needed.

Comment: Please format your controller code to make it readable.

Comment: `to_xls` in a hash gives you a xls string?

Comment: 90% sure thats line is the problem: ` Order.where(status_id: Orders::Status.where(name: ['COMPLETED', 
   'INPROGRESS' ]).pluck(:id))
      .includes(:status, :platform, :payment).map{|order|{id: order.id, 
                 txnid: order.txnid, 
                 created_at: order.created_at, product: order.product,
                 payment: order.payment.status.name, 
                 status: order.status.name, total_amount: 
                 order.total_amount, discount: order.discount, 
                 platform: order.platform.name 
               }}.to_xls,`

Comment: Yeah I presume the same . I tried the following : Order.joins(:status, 
       :payment, :platform).where(status_id: Orders::Status.where(name: ['COMPLETED', 'INPROGRESS' ]).pluck(:id)).select('orders.id, orders.txnid, orders.created_at, orders.product, statuses.name as status_name, orders.total_amount, orders.discount, platforms.name as platform') .to_xls  . It shows misssing where cluase for statuses. PLEASE help me get -  @lcguida

Answer (score 0):

```
My choice is to just manually generate CSV file like this :

@orders = Order.all

header = ["id", "status" // put your header field ]

csv = CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << header
    @orders.each do |order|
      row = [ordrer.id, order.total_amount //mention your fields here  ]  
    end 
 csv << row

end
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that too. but for link button with path orders_path, it shows template missing  and when I directluy add the hard coded link "/admin/orders.xls" , it creates a  spreadsheet with no content data exported in it.- @Amit Attri

Comment: put the above code on your model in a class method and  make a call to it like this : 
format.csv {
                     send_date Order.to_csv(request.host_with_port),
                      :type => ''text/csv;"
                 }